# Java Generics & Reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

this probably is a basic question, but can I do something like this:

```
Class myClass = Class.forName("Integer");
SomethingSimple<myClass> obj;
```

Where SomethingSimple is a very *simple* generic class:

```
class SomethingSimple<T>
{
    T value;
    SomethingSimple() {}
    public void setT(T val)
    {
        value = val;
    }
    public T getT()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Obviously, the code above is not correct, since myClass is an object of type Class, and a class is required. The question is how can this be achieved. I read the other topics about Generics Reflection, but they concerned how the generic class knows the type.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305629/generics-and-reflection-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics in Java are used only for static type checking at compile time; the generic information is discarded after type checking (read about [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)) so a `SomethingSimple<Foo>` is effectively just a `SomethingSimple<Object>` at runtime.

Naturally, you can't do comple-time type checking on a type that isn't known until runtime.  The type has to be known to the compiler, which is why you have to use an actual type name rather than a `Class` variable as the generic type parameter.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do that. What's the point? Generics give you compile-time type checking and if the class isn't known until runtime, you don't gain anything.

Answer (score 2):

Generics is a compile time mechanism to ensure type safety, and reflection is a runtime mechanism. What you're saying is, "I don't know at compile time what the type of T is but I want compile time type safety" (which doesn't make much sense). To put it another way, java erases the type of T at runtime and stores it as an Object...so the type of T (as far as generics are concerned) no longer matters.

But really it seems like you want a dependency injection container, like spring or google guise.

Comment: Information about generics is NOT completely lost in runtime - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html
and related methods like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericReturnType