# Why do I get the base class methods via reflection when the subclass overrides them?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, reflection

I have super class as:

```
class MyClass<T> {
  public void setValue(T value){
    //insert code
  }

  public T getValue(){
    return null;
  }
}
```

then I have a a specific derivation

```
class MyClassImp extends MyClass<String> {
  @Override
  public void setValue(String value){
    //insert code
  }

  @Override
  public String getValue(){
    return null;
  }
}
```

On reflection on `MyClassImpl` as:

```
Class clazz = MyClassImpl.class;
Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
```

I get both superclass implementation `java.lang.Object getValue()`, `void setValue(java.lang.Object)` and `java.lang.String getValue()`, `void setValue(java.lang.String)`.

According to the Java documentation of `Class.getDeclaredMethods()` vis-a-viz

> Returns an array of Method objects reflecting all the methods declared by the class or interface represented by this Class object. This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private methods, but excludes inherited methods. The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any particular order. This method returns an array of length 0 if the class or interface declares no methods, or if this Class object represents a primitive type, an array class, or void. The class initialization method `<clinit>` is not included in the returned array. If the class declares multiple public member methods with the same parameter types, they are all included in the returned array.

Why am I getting the super type implementation?
Is there something I am missing?

The reason why I need this is that I reflectively invoke `setValue` on base class implementation, which I have added some special annotation comments and of course additional constraints.

Comment: May be a duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756081/java-generics-reflection

Comment: @RC: I don't see how it could be a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @RC this is not a exact duplicate

Answer (score 14):

It's because the compiled class actually *does* declare `setValue(Object)`. That method will cast to String, and then call the strongly typed method. Likewise `getValue(Object)` calls `getValue(String)`.

Basically this is required because the JVM doesn't really know about generics (at least not in a deep way) - in order to override the superclass method at the JVM level, it has to have the same signature.

Have a look at the class with `javap -c MyclassImp` you'll see the extra synthetic methods:

```
public java.lang.Object getValue();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokevirtual   #3; //Method getValue:()Ljava/lang/String;
   4:   areturn

public void setValue(java.lang.Object);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   aload_1
   2:   checkcast       #4; //class java/lang/String
   5:   invokevirtual   #5; //Method setValue:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   8:   return

}
```

Comment: Note that `Method.isSynthetic()` will return `true` for those generated methods that take/return `Object`. That's a good way to distinguish those methods from the "real" ones.

Comment: Is this compiler behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: @Ryan: I don't know, I'm afraid. Looking briefly over the JLS, I can't see it - although this sort of situation is mentioned in a few places.

Comment: @Joh, I was wondering why the documentation says the call to method  Class.getDeclaredMethods() will exclude the inherited methods.

Comment: @Santosh: It excludes methods which are inherited but not overridden. In this case, both methods are overridden. I agree it could be clearer.

Comment: Thank you guys. I never understood what synthetic meant until you referred me to the JLS. problem solved

Comment: @Maress, The extra methods you see are not the inherited methods, they are generated method with the same signature.  If you look at the methods for `MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethods()` you will find these methods are not exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon had said earlier, **type information is lost at runtime for generics**.

So whenever you use generics, the compiler puts all those "generic" inherited methods in the subclass. The same is not true with non-generic code.

I just checked: when I removed the generic related code (the `<T>` part) from the superclass and the reflection code gave me exactly two methods in the subclass even though it overrides them. It implies that the documentation should have been a little bit explicit for generic-related code.

Comment: Strictly speaking those methods aren't there because of the generics (as you've noticed). They are there because the methods use return type covariance (i.e. the sub class returns a more specific value than the base type). That is *most often* used in combination with generics, but can be used stand-alone.

Comment: yes i have verified all the scenarios, where i override in generic form and explicit form. with generic form, i only have two methods, with covariance, i noticed the two additional methods and they are marked as synthetic